# Update php config file from php form

Tags: php, config

I'm in the process of developing a GUI in php and want to be able to update the config file from a form within the GUI.

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_PORT', 3306); 
define('DB_USER', 'dbuser1');
define('DB_PASS', 'dbpass');
```

What I would like to do is search for variable and replace the value. Here's an idea that I had to replace the line:

```
$file = 'config.php';
$strSearch = define('DB_USER', 'dbuser1');
$strReplace = define('DB_USER', 'dbuser2');
file_put_contents($file, str_replace($strSearch, $strReplace, file_get_contents($file)));
```

It could probably be done better if we could simply search for the variable 'DB_USER' and then just change the value 'dbuser1' to 'dbuser2' with preg_match or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change `$strSearch = define('DB_USER', 'dbuser1');` into `$strSearch = "define('DB_USER', 'dbuser1');"` That way it will be a string that you can use in str_replace

The function define will return true or false the way you write it now.

Comment: Yeah, but what I'm looking for is a method to directly search for DB_USER and then only replace dbuser1 to dbuser2 as an example, instead of the whole string.

Comment: maybe you can save the file structure as a json string then you can easly get and set the variables and then, after setting all the variables right you can loop though the json and write the variables to the file. So you will have then a config.php file and a config.json file